# Would this way be the correct way to say 'reversed'?

Tags: traducción, gramática, vocabulario

I am trying to say:

> Finally, I believe that the negative effects of globalization would be
>   able to be stopped if the politicians worked to reverse the effects
>   now.

So I came up with the sentence:

> Finalmente, creo que los efectos negativos de globalización podrían
>   ser evitado si los políticos trabajaron para invertir los efectos
>   ahora.

I know *invertir* also means "to invest". Is it correct to use it as "revert" in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the right word would be "revertir".

It is true that "invertir" may mean "invest", but it can also mean "invert" (not "reverse").

Notice that your translation contains a few mistakes:

> Finalmente, creo que los efectos negativos de LA globalización podrían ser evitadoS si los políticos trabajarAn para REvertir los efectos ahora. <sub>(I don't like this "ahora", and would feel more inclined to use "ahora mismo", "ya mismo", "de inmediato".)</sub>

Comment: `Trabajaran` as in the future? Would it be more correct to use that than the preterite in this instance?

Comment: @SquidDev Not "trabajarán" (future), but "trabajaran" (without a written stress). "trabajaran" is the imperfect preterite of the subjunctive and, just like "worked", it can be used to refer to the future when combined with a conditional tense: *Sería bueno que trabajaran...* (It'd be good/fine if they worked...)